# Multipass with Python VENV

Tags: 18.04, python, multipass

I am trying to make a venv with Python with Multipass and I have a folder mounted, however, when I try to create the venv, it gives me this message:

`Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/ubuntu/C:/dev/multipass_files/primary/`

If you xan help with this that would be great. Thanks :)

I SOLVED IT, NO LONGER NEED HELP

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, would you mind share your solution as an answer below. Check [about] to see how this site works (It is a Q&A site)